# pasting "::" and "Foo" does not give a valid preprocessing token

Tags: c++, macros, preprocessor-directive

I would like to attach MyNamespace:: to the function defined by the macro:

```
#define transFunc(func)                                                    \
dimensionedScalar func(const dimensionedScalar& ds)                        \
{                                                                          \
    if (!ds.dimensions().dimensionless())                                  \
    {                                                                      \
        FatalErrorIn(#func "(const dimensionedScalar& ds)")                \
            << "ds not dimensionless"                                      \
            << abort(FatalError);                                          \
    }                                                                      \
                                                                           \
    return dimensionedScalar                                               \
    (                                                                      \
        #func "(" + ds.name() + ')',                                       \
        dimless,                                                           \
        MyNameSpace::##func(ds.value())                                                 \
    );                  

                                               \
```

}

But When I call

```
transFunc(Foo)
```

the compiler throws the following error :

> pasting "::" and "Foo" does not give a valid preprocessing token

What is wrong about the way I concatenate tokens above?

Comment: Can I be obnoxious and ask *why* this needs to be a macro, as opposed to a template function? We also have `std::function` now as well.

Comment: @Bathsheba, this is code from an opensource project. I am overloading double type to my user-defined datatype.

Answer (score 7):

`##` is used to bodge two tokens together to make a single token. So something like `func##1` would expand to the single token `func1`.

Using it here, it tries to bodge together `::` and `Foo` to make a single token `::Foo`. As the error says, that's not a valid token. You don't want a single token here; you just want to keep the two tokens separate:

```
MyNameSpace::func(ds.value())
```

Comment: but when it bodges :: and Foo to make ::Foo, which ultimately gives
Mynamespace::Foo. I dont see any thing wrong with this...

Comment: @cpp_noname If you write `Mynamespace::Foo` in normal code, it's three tokens: `MyNamespace`, `::` and `Foo`.

Comment: @cpp_noname: Tokens are not delimited by spaces necessarily :)

Comment: @cpp_noname: No, that's parsed as three separate tokens, `Mynamespace`, `::` and `Foo`, which between them form a valid C++ expression. `::Foo`, as a single token, is not valid. That's what the (incorrect) use of `##` tries to create.

Answer (score 2):

The `##` works for macros, It doesn't meant to work in a regular code.

You can do it as follows:

```
#define ADD_NAMESPACE(NS,FUNC) NS##::##FUNC
```

Now you can use it like this:

```
ADD_NAMESPACE(std,cout)<<x1<<ADD_NAMESPACE(std,endl);
```

But you **can't** do like this:

```
std ## :: ## cout<<std ## :: ## endl;
```

You just do:

```
std::cout<<std::endl;
```

**EDIT**

this example worked with gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-16) (GCC):

```
#include <iostream>
#define ADD_NAMESPACE(NS,FUNC) NS##::##FUNC
int main()
{
  ADD_NAMESPACE(std,cout)<<"hello world!"<<ADD_NAMESPACE(std,endl);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which compiler does that succeed with? For example, GCC 4.8.3 throws the same error as in original post, but now regarding `NS` and `::`; however, simply writing `MyNameSpace::func(ds.value())` as in the answer by Mike Seymour somehow works — despite that simplified parsers, like KDevelop's built-in analyzer, understands that literally.

Comment: @AntonSamsonov I added full example with gcc version. If you've got stray ## error, I think you tried the `std ## :: ## cout<<std ## :: ## endl;` which specified under **But you can't do like this:**

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, ## concatenates two tokens at (or after) the tokenizing stage of compilation:

```
a##b => (a) ## (b) => (ab)
( possibly invalid, like (::bar) instead of (::), (bar) )
```

**Note, this doesn't send concatenated token identifiers back through the tokenizer, that stage of compilation is already done.**  What might be messing you up is that these are now tokens, not raw strings anymore.

---

As I came (late to the party) here looking for the same information, here's a foo.cpp sample if things still don't make sense:

```
#define FOO(a) Something::a

int main()
{
        FOO( bar );
        FOO( cat );

        return 0;
}
```

*gcc -E foo.cpp*  produces

```
# 1 "foo.cpp"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 1 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "foo.cpp"



int main()
{
 Something::bar;
 Something::cat;

 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about adding a prefix to your function, for instance '_':

```
dimensionedScalar _##func(const dimensionedScalar& ds)
```

Then you could concatenate '_' with func:

```
MyNameSpace::_##func(ds.value())
```